# CKDiscoverAllContactsOperation not fetching contacts

Tags: objective-c, ios8, cloudkit, icloud-api

I am using `CKDiscoverAllContactsOperation` but its not working fine for me.

```
-(void)queryForAllUsers: (void (^)(NSArray *records))completionHandler {

    CKDiscoverAllContactsOperation *op = [[CKDiscoverAllContactsOperation alloc] init];

    [op setUsesBackgroundSession:YES];
    op.queuePriority = NSOperationQueuePriorityNormal;

    [op setDiscoverAllContactsCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *userInfos, NSError *error) {

        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"An error occured in %@: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), error);
            //abort();
        } else {

            NSLog(@"Number of records in userInfos is: %ld", (unsigned long)[userInfos count]);
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                completionHandler(userInfos);
            });
        }
    }];
    [self.container addOperation:op];
}
```

The container which I'm using is `publicCloudDatabase`.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working fine for me'? Not working at all? Error message?

Comment: Your code is correct, and I assume the problem is that you didn't log in into iCloud account.

Answer (score 4):

The search only works if different users activate the app, approved to be Discoverable and have the other person's iCloud email address in their Contacts.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the discoverAllContactUserInfosWithCompletionHandler on the container like this:

```
[self.container discoverAllContactUserInfosWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *userInfos, NSError *error) {
.. 
}
```

this function will only return the contacts that can be linked to an iCloud account and the person has also started up your app.

Comment: Hi edwin, I have already tried with this but its still not working. you have any other alternate option then that?

Comment: Maybe you answered no on the prompt if your app should be allowed to do this? See your settings, privacy, contacts, your app

Comment: It is functioning in my code that you can find at https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao (sorry, it's written in Swift)

Comment: Hi edwin, i have tried this code but i m enable to see that one, as i'm not finding left menu button.can u please suggest me? what is going wrong.

Comment: ah, i see the menu buttons are gone from the first form. You can still swipe the from left  edge to right to show the menu

Comment: I fixed the menu on startup issue. The change is now on github

Comment: I have tried your code but i m not getting any contacts. when i have run this code i m getting "AllContactUserInfo count = 0" while in address book i m having around 5 contacts. what is going wrong here??

Comment: you will only see the contacts where the registration can be linked to an iCloud id and that person did start up your app before. The best way to test this is by using 2 devices both with a different iCloud account and where each have the other in their contact list.

Comment: @EdwinVermeer he shouldn't. You answer is alternative, and as for me I prefer NSOperation variant due to priority control setting.

Comment: Having a similar issue, except sometimes it returns an array and sometimes it's blank. Almost like the back end is deciding not to always send the list. Maybe only if a new user is detected the list is returned?

Comment: I have seen similar behavior. I think there is a limitation for the amount of times you are allowed to query your contacts. So you should keep a list of the contacts yourself and update that list with new contacts if it does return them