# CloudKit Discovery discoverAllContactUserInfosWithCompletionHandler returns empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, icloud, cloudkit

Here's the goal:

1. User A and User B are users of the app.
2. They are using separate devices logged into separate iCloud accounts.
3. Both users enable discoverability in the app.
4. Once enabled, User A can see that User B is using the app, and vice versa (assuming both have each other's iCloud emails in their contact books).

Currently, I've followed through the following steps, but `discoverAllContactUserInfosWithCompletionHandler` returns empty.
I'm stumped. I've:

1. Configured the app for CloudKit
2. Am checking the status with
   `accountStatusWithCompletionHandler`. I am receiving `accountStatus == .Available`
3. Check discovery permission with `statusForApplicationPermission(CKApplicationPermissions.PermissionUserDiscoverability)`. I am receiving `permissionStatus == .Granted`
4. I now request app users using `discoverAllContactUserInfosWithCompletionHandler`. In the completion block, I receive no error and an empty users array. I've also tried using `discoverUserInfoWithEmailAddress` to pull a user that I've registered with on a separate device. This returns a nil user object, but no error.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Any advice/troubleshooting tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CKDiscoverAllContactsOperation not fetching contacts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25847340/ckdiscoverallcontactsoperation-not-fetching-contacts)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer - [CKDiscoverAllContactsOperation not fetching contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25847340/ckdiscoverallcontactsoperation-not-fetching-contacts/28470903#28470903)

The other users must enable Discoverability on their iCloud account with your app AND use the same email address as stored in your Contacts.